# Depth perception - detect how far into a scene a user is looking

Tags: algorithms, terminology

I would like to know about how we can detect how 'deep' into a scene a user is looking. If looking into a 3D environment, with an object close to the user and one further away, how can we detect when the user is looking at the object further away? Or, rather, how can we detect which object a user is looking at in a 3D environment?

I am asking here because I'm not sure what this technology is called, or even if it exists, and so am hoping for some pointers into what I should be reading/looking at.

If anyone has some resources for me (links, algorithm names, books, articles, etc.), it would help a lot, but if you are able to explain a little, I'd really appreciate that, too.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is that about analyzing how a scene is rendered, or measuring the actual onlooker's eyes seen through a camera?

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, it's about detecting what object in a 3D scene a person is looking at - what he/she is focusing on. Imagine a camera (or some other vision tracking apparatus above your monitor) tracking your eyes and you are looking into a 3D scene: how can we detect on which object the user is focusing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the gaze direction angles of each eye (as well as head position and orientation), then the corresponding rays intersect roughly at the fixation point in 3D. 
This straightforward approach should work in theory, but in practice it is still quite challenging due to both technical and physiological factors.

[Pfeiffer, Latoschik and Wachsmuth](http://www.hci.uni-wuerzburg.de/download/evaluation-of-eyetrackers-JVRB08.pdf) summarize quite accessibly the state of the art in 3D eye-fixation tracking as in 2008. Here, the intuitive approach I just described was still outperformed by another algorithm.

As the following link suggests, however, the problems with geometrical approaches may have been resolved since 2008. [This commercial application](http://www.arringtonresearch.com/3Dheadandeyetracking.html) appears to use the intersection-point method, though I doubt that the applied algorithms are published.